# Vertical line doesn't take up the entire page?

Tags: css, html, height, width

I'm working on a page that is split into three columns. There are two lines, one between each column. The line on the right takes up the entire page, whereas the left line stops with the text. Here's a picture of the page. Ignore the empty divs, I used them as a test.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvU8F.png

Before you read the code, I would like to first state that the left column comes first, the right column comes second, and the middle column comes last. The code for the lines are at the beginning of the left and right column sections of the code. The code is here:

http://pastebin.com/9MBChNMz

Comment: Please put relevant code in your question

Comment: Please post your code on CodePen/JSFiddle, or somewhere where we can see it.

Comment: Sorry, but it is impossible to read it like that - use http://jsfiddle.net to create an example - an don't use inline CSS (!)

Comment: I think the issue is about the columns not having equal height. There are techniques to make the vertical borders take the longest column's height. Here are some techniques to get you started: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Answer (score 0):

I think its all dependent on which Div you placed that border.. Maybe the div you have that border on is shorter than the other div; this means the line won't go all the way down.. Check that + code would be extremely helpful